# on second cohomology of $S^1$-manifold

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology

Let $M$ be a closed oriented real manifold with a free smooth circle action. Denote $BS^1$ to be the classifying space of principal circle bundles and $ES^1\rightarrow BS^1$ to be the universal principal circle bundle.

Now we consider the fibre product $M_{S^1}:=M\times_{S^1}ES^1$. When the fundamental group $\pi_1(M)=0$, one can show that $$H^2(M_{S^1}, \mathbb{Z})\cong H^2(M, \mathbb{Z})\oplus \mathbb{Z}.\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (\star)$$

My question is: Is it possible to loosen the condition "$\pi_1(M)=0$"? For example, does $(\star)$ still hold true if we only assume $H^1(M, \mathbb{Z})=0$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. This follows from the Leray-Serre spectral sequence of the fibre bundle
$$
M\to M_{S^1} \to BS^1
$$
which has $E_2^{p,q}=H^p(BS^1;H^q(M;\mathbb{Z}))$ and converges to (the associated graded of the filtration on) $H^*(M_{S^1};\mathbb{Z})$. Note that $BS^1\simeq \mathbb{C}P^\infty$ has cohomology concentrated in even degrees. So the only possible differentials into or out of the diagonal $p+q=2$ are $$d_2:H^0(BS^1;H^2(M;\mathbb{Z}))\to H^2(BS^1;H^1(M;\mathbb{Z}))$$ and $$d_2:H^0(BS^1;H^1(M;\mathbb{Z}))\to H^2(BS^1;H^0(M;\mathbb{Z})),$$ both of which must be zero if we assume that $H^1(M;\mathbb{Z})=0$.